# Get JTextField string and insert into Google search

Tags: java, jframe, jtextfield

I want to build an application where a user inserts a String into a textfield and when he clicks a search button it redirects them to google with the search results displayed in google that match the string entered in the jtextfield in the application.

So for example if I type on the jtextfield "Java" and then press a search button, I want it to be equivalent to me typing "Java" directly on to Google.
Is this possible?

Also, is it possible to have a dropdown list with suggestions? And when you click a suggestion it either fills the textfield in with the suggestion or automatically searches that suggestion (either one of those not both)

Note that I'm a fairly new programmer :)

Comment: Do you actually want to start the browser?

Comment: @SamDunk yes i would like to start the browser

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  try {
         String search = "#q="+jTextField.getText().toString().trim();
         search = search.replaceAll(" ","+");
         String url = "http:////www.google.com//"+search;
         java.awt.Desktop.getDesktop().browse(java.net.URI.create(url));
       }
       catch (java.io.IOException e) {
           System.out.println(e.getMessage());
       }
```

Answer (score 0):

I just changed the ActionListener of the Oracle tutorial's class SimpleSwingBrowser. The text field enables to search via Google : [sample of code](http://pastebin.com/Lx50FyP4).